# Python3.9: AssertionError while making a test (Learn Python 3 the Hard Way ex49)

Tags: python

I'm doing an exercise in the book "Learn Python 3 the Hard Way", and I was instructed to code up a test for the following code:

```
def peek(word_list):
    if word_list:
        word = word_list[0]
        return word[0]
    else:
        return None

def match(word_list, expecting):
    if word_list:
        word = word_list.pop(0)

        if word[0] == expecting:
            return word
        else:
            return None
    else:
        return None

def skip(word_list, word_type):
    while peek(word_list) == word_type:
        match(word_list, word_type)


def parse_verb(word_list):
    skip(word_list, 'stop')
    next_word = peek(word_list)

    if next_word == 'verb':
        return match(word_list, 'verb')
    else:
        return ParserError("Expected a verb next.")
```

I'm specifically trying to test the `parse_verb` function. This is my version of the code for the test:

```
def test_verb():
    assert_raises(parser.ParserError, parser.parse_verb, [('noun', 'princess'),
                                                          ('verb', 'open'),
                                                          ('stop', 'the'),
                                                          ('noun', 'door')])
```

Testing the code on Terminal using nosetests, I got this error message:

```
$ nosetests
............F
======================================================================
FAIL: tests.parser_tests.test_verb
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/lpthw3/projects/ex48/tests/parser_tests.py", line 35, in test_verb
    assert_raises(parser.ParserError, parser.parse_verb, [('noun', 'princess'), ('verb', 'open'), ('stop', 'the'), ('noun', 'door')])
AssertionError: ParserError not raised by parse_verb
```

May I ask why did I get this error message? Shouldn't ParserError be raised according to the code?

Comment: You are seeing that error because you are failing your test case. Your trying to call `assert_raises`, and you are failing because, as your stack trace says, `ParserError not raised by parse_verb` , which in turn `raises` an `AssertionError` in the context of your test.

Comment: You have to `raise` the error instead of using `return`.